# General question on norm and distance in a normed vector space E and a continuous linear form u.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let E be a normed vector space and u be a linear, continuous form on E with kernel H.

We show that: $\forall x \in E \setminus H, \| u \| \le \frac{|u(x)|}{d(x, H)}.$

$\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}, \forall y \in H,$

$\frac{|u(\lambda x + y)|}{\|\lambda x + y\|} = \frac{|\lambda||u(x)|}{|\lambda|\|x+\frac{1}{\lambda}y\|} = \frac{|u(x)|}{\|x+\frac{1}{\lambda}y\|} \le \frac{|u(x)|}{d(x,H)}.$

My question is on the last inequality (in particular, the denominator), comparing the norm on E and the distance d(x,H):

So, if I am correct:

$d(x,H) \le d(x,\frac{1}{\lambda}y) = \|x-\frac{1}{\lambda}y\| \le \|x+\frac{1}{\lambda}y\|$

So here, to compare the distance and the norm on E, we assume that $\|w \|:= d(0,w)$,  $\forall w \in E$ ; that is the norm on the normed vector space E is the distance from a point w and the origin 0? (My confusion is E is a general normed vector space). Can someone please elaborate, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track, simply adding a minus will solve the problem:
$$d(x,H)\leq d(x,-\frac1{\lambda}y)=\|x+\frac1{\lambda}y\|$$

Comment: I see, the way you did it is more direct. So, does the distance between two vectors in E equal the norm of the difference between the two vectors? How do we know this when the norm is not specified in the question (E a normed vector space)? I was interested if you could talk about the connection between the distance as shown and the norm on E.

Comment: Every norm naturally induces a metric by $d(x,y):=\|x-y\|$. You can check that the defining properties of a norm imply the defining properties of a metric here. Therefore, whenever we talk about a normed vector space, the induced metric is always assumed, unless specified otherwise.